# my base_path not working properly when accessing page with https or http

Tags: php, path

I have hosted a site at Godaddy and is accessible via https and http.
I have declared a BASE_PATH var globally on my conf.php as:

```
define('BASE_URL','//theventuregame.com');
```

And I use this BASE_URL var almost everywhere on my site.. the problem is when people visit it using like http://theventuregame.com or https://theventuregame.com it all works fine.. but when they try typing www.theventuregame.com that redirects to https://www.theventuregame.com and that BASE_PATH is diffirent from the URL and makes problem.

How do I make my BASE_PATH always same as people access the page???
I am using this into httaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

to always redirect site to https so i can have my BASE_PATH as:

```
define('BASE_URL','https://www.theventuregame.com');
```

but some people goes direclty to site as theventuregame.com and that redirects them to https://theventuregame.com and my BASE_PATH is again different..

I hope i was clear with my question..

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the PHP `$_SERVER` variables to determine the base URL of the website.

For my website, i use this string:

```
$siteRootUrl = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/";
```

This sets the protocol and the host using the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, and then concatenates into a root URL string.

A string like that may help you, you could then call `define('BASE_URL', $siteRootUrl);` and still use it site wide. Then it wouldn't matter whether people accessed your website via HTTP or HTTPS, or whether they use www. or not.

Have a look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) for some more information on the PHP `$_SERVER` superglobal.

Just as a side note, if you're running HTTPS then its better to keep forcing people to use HTTPS to keep the security there.